# Heads up Or Notification banner not pop ups from top when app in background or killed state || react-native-firebase || fcm

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

When I send notification in Background or killed state, Notification silently push into Notification tray no pop up showing. I read various question and discussion on this topic, but never found clear way to achieved my goal.
Here are my versions.

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.1.0",
@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^10.2.0"
```

And I am sending notification like this,

```
await fetch("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", {
method: "post",
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
   Authorization: "key",
},
 body: JSON.stringify({
  to: token,
  notification: {
    title: partner.name,
    body: `someone Hired you for job, kindly contact `,
    sound: "default",
   },
   data: customerData,
 }),
});
```

Comment: do you found any solution ?